# Swap flex boxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Please tell me how I can swap the blue and green blocks. But so that the blocks left2 and right2 remain in place. Thank you in advance.
`Order` most likely will not work, because I don't know how many blocks there will be.

```css
#flex {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#flex #center {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

#flex #right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

#flex #left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

#flex #right2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
}

#flex #left2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
  <div id="center"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="left2"></div>
  <div id="right2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not just swap the `color` attribute? or switch between the `id` (`left`, `right`)?

Comment: I think it would be easier to swap boxes in a grid layout without affecting other boxes. You could use `grid-area` property for defining row and column in which each box should be placed. Grid layout will provide you with more flexibility as compared to flexbox.

Comment: @Yousaf I can't change it in the grid, since the blocks are output from the database in a different order (as in this case, first the right block and then the left one).

Comment: Why the blue and green? What's the logic behind those two in particular?

Comment: Flex items can be arranged using the [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#the_order_property) property.

Comment: @Yousaf he said `Order most likely will not work, because I don't know how many blocks there will be.`, I think you should comment on that

Comment: As you can't modify the html, I can't think of any other way to re-arrange the flex items. If you could edit the html, then one way to achieve the desired result is to have each row in a separate flex container and you can reverse the order using the `flex-direction` property.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the 2nd and 3rd child that are swapped, then `order` will work:

```css
#flex {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#flex .center {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

#flex .right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

#flex .left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}

#flex .right2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
}

#flex .left2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
}

#flex>div {
  /* keep everything after the first three divs in their original order */
  order: 4;
}

#flex>div:first-child {
  /* keep first div where it is */
  order: 1;
}


/* Change the order of the 2nd and third divs */
#flex>div:nth-child(2) {
  order: 3;
}

#flex>div:nth-child(3) {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left2"></div>
  <div class="right2"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left2"></div>
  <div class="right2"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left2"></div>
  <div class="right2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would work. I think his question is ambiguous, because he said `the blocks are output from the database in a different order` in a comment, so they won't always be 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: See what OP says but this answers the original question - they may have more caveats but won't know until they comment on this